# How to truncate a time of datetime in python and wrt to postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

If I have a datetime object of abc=  `2021-03-11 21:14:21.043000+00:00` how do I convert it to `2021-03-11 21:14:21` using python? I am trying to insert this particular value into my postgresql column having column's datatype as timestamp and it gives me an error like

```
[parameters: (datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 11, 21, 14, 21, 43000, tzinfo=<UTC>))]
```

The datetime: `2021-03-11 21:14:21.043000+00:00` is coming from python and I am trying to insert this in postgresql.
How do I solve this? Help me out.

**Edit**:
I also tried to use time() on a datetime object but it gave an attribute error.
here's what I did:

````
last_file_ran_time = last_file_run_time.rsplit('.')[0]```
values = last_file_run, last_file_ran_time
db.execute("""INSERT INTO gcs_file_info_table (last_file_run, last_file_run_time) VALUES (?,?) """, values)
print("data inserted")
````

And here's the error:

```
LINE 1: ...info_table (last_file_run, last_file_run_time) VALUES (?,?) 
                                                                   ^

[SQL: INSERT INTO gcs_file_info_table (last_file_run, last_file_run_time) VALUES (?,?) ]
[parameters: ('xyz.json', datetime.time(21, 14, 21, 43000))]
```

Comment: Which framework are you using to access the database? I thought most of them convert the datetime automatically...

Comment: Also, what's the full error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the datetime with f-strings or the .strftime method, but you probably shouldn't need to; depending on which framework/library you're using, it should convert the datetime automatically.

So the options, in the order of preference:

- Check your framework/library (you don't say which one you're using) for instructions on how to pass a datetime as a parameter; this is the best option by far.
- If that doesn't work, format the date as you might for printing it out, using either an f-string:

  ```
  f"{the_date:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"
  ```

  or, using the strftime method

  ```
  the_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  ```

---

**Edit:** The error you're seeing is not caused by the date; it's caused by using `?` as the placeholder, while the library requires `%s`

```
db.execute("""INSERT INTO gcs_file_info_table (last_file_run, last_file_run_time) VALUES (%s, %s) """, values)
```

Comment: the_date.strftime for sure converted the date..I guess now the error is somewhere near inserting the value in postgresql. I am using postgresql for that

Comment: Yeah, the error was never in the date; it was by using `?` rather than `%s`. You can probably get rid of the `.strftime()`...

Comment: Ah! how could I miss that. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that the Python database API standard has five options for the placeholders, rather than specifying one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Variable.time() will give you time factor of datetime
`
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
x.time()
`

Comment: can you share the screenshot as it should work
'''
x = datetime.datetime.now()
x.time()
'''